# Generating a Google Hanghouts meeting URL

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'd like my website to be able to programmatically generate Hangouts URLs that can be forwarded to specific users in order for them to join the same meeting.
To my understanding, this would be possible by scheduling an event via `Google Calendar`. Is there a way to do the same without relying on `Google Calendar`, meaning via an `API` call or something similar?

Comment: There's no indication of creating `hangoutsLink` outside of Calendar API, it seems its the only option we have at the moment. The Google+ Hangouts API deals with creating apps inside a Hangout. The only reference we have for it is inside the [Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)

Answer (score 4):

You can now quickly create a new meeting by going to

http://meet.google.com/new

This makes for an excellent bookmark!

Answer (score 2):

Meeting URLs can be generated with no API calls. Try:

`g.co/hangout/yourdomain.com/letshangout`

However, guests who aren't part of your domain won't be able to join until a domain member joins and changed to hangout privacy to anyone with the link.

Comment: This URL is no longer valid after the transition to Google Meet.

Comment: @lid check my answer for the new URL!